# How do I go about removing a garage with asbestos wall panels?

Tags: garage, asbestos, demolition

I have a 1904 house and it has a shed that was put in some time in the 1950s. It's a wonky structure made of wooden beams and thin sheets of asbestos panels make up the walls. We want to tear it down and put a log wood cabin in.

My local authority has a dump site that allows you to dump asbestos and other hazardous materials, so disposing of it will not be a problem.

This question was more a case of how to dismantle it, are any special tools needed and most importantly, what special hazard tools will I need?

Comment: I have worked with companies to remove asbestos from job sites. they usually have high end respirators to block any dust from being breathed in. They also wear tyvek jump suits and gloves  with the wrist taped to the glove. Last they wet the material down with a garden sprayer prior to pulling it off to minimize the dust. These were the big things they did. A new suit and respirator filter each day, suit in the trash and respirator wiped down prior to removal with damp towels. OOPS forgot they also wore rubber boots with the legs taped to the boots, these were also wiped down also.

Comment: It was just as @EdBeal describes when our asbestos roof was removed. Plus, each piece of asbestos was wrapped and sealed into clear plastic sheeting or bags. Then they swept the garage carefully and put the debris into sealed plastic bags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asbestos is exceptionally dangerous if disturbed. The regs are very strict and this is as I am sure you will know, just one fibre inhaled can cause respiratory cancer (years after), this is well documented. It is expensive I am sure but I would certainly get a experts to advise. This is not a DIY project unless you get properly insured and kitted and this in itself is far more a pain.